# Javascript Salary Calculator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an annual salary calculator using Javascript. Here is what I have so far:

```js
<div id="fulldiv">
  <p> Enter the following information to calculate your annual salary.</p>
     
  <p>Hourly Wage:
  <input type="text" name="wage" id="txt_wage" value ="0.00"/></p>
     
  <p>Hours Per Week:
  <input type="text" name="hours" id="txt_hours" value= "0.0"/> <br/><br/>
  
  <button value="calculate" onclick="calcSalary()">Calculate</button></p>
  
  <p id="results"></p>
     
  <script type="text/javascript">
  
  function calcSalary() {
  var wage_element = document.getElementById('txt_wage');
  var wage = parseInt(wage_element.value);
  var hours_element = document.getElementById('txt_hours');
  var hours = parseInt(hours_element.value);
  var calculate = wage_element * hours_element * 52;
  document.getElementByID('results').innerHTML = calculate;
  }
  </script>
    
     
    

</div>
```

When I click the button, nothing happens. Any thoughts?

Comment: **Java (not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some typos in there. I have slightly rewritten and simplified the code to ensure the a) your calculations are on the value of the inputs and b) you are using labels to provide the text relative to the inputs - not p's.

```js
function calcSalary() {
 var wage = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txt_wage').value);
 var hours = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txt_hours').value);
 var calculate = wage * hours * 52;
 
 document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = calculate;
}
```

```html
<div id="fulldiv">
 <p> Enter the following information to calculate your annual salary.</p>
 <label for="txt_wage">Hourly Wage:</label>
 <input type="text" name="wage" id="txt_wage" value ="0.00"/>
     
 <label for="txt_hours">Hours Per Week:</label>
 <input type="text" name="hours" id="txt_hours" value= "0.0"/>   
  <br/><br/>
 <button value="calculate" onclick="calcSalary()">Calculate</button>
 <p id="results"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but the javascript code goes inside the div tags, correct? I see you have them separately. Is this just for if you're using an external file?

Comment: yes -  you want all the javascript out of the div  tags - the function of the div tags is to define the boundaries  of the html elements within the page - the javascript is there to create the funcitonality of the elemetns. Ideally - you would also remove the onclick event handler in the html and have an event listener in the js that then allows the function on the click. Same deal forthe CSS - bst to not have inline styling - have in the css section either at the top of the page (in the head) or in an external css file that is then called into the page.

Answer (score 1):

You code needs to be adjusted

```
var calculate = wage_element * hours_element * 52;
```

Should be changed into

```
var calculate = wage * hours * 52;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calculating the element instead of the values.

@Gerard beat me to it by a minute, but here's the working code.

```html
<div id="fulldiv">
  <p> Enter the following information to calculate your annual salary.</p>
     
  <p>Hourly Wage:
  <input type="text" name="wage" id="txt_wage" value ="0.00"/></p>
     
  <p>Hours Per Week:
  <input type="text" name="hours" id="txt_hours" value= "0.0"/> <br/><br/>
  
  <button value="calculate" onclick="calcSalary()">Calculate</button></p>
  
  <p id="results"></p>
     
  <script type="text/javascript">
  
  function calcSalary() {
      var wage_element = document.getElementById('txt_wage');
      var wage = parseInt(wage_element.value);
      var hours_element = document.getElementById('txt_hours');
      var hours = parseInt(hours_element.value);
      
      var calculate = wage * hours * 52;
      document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = calculate;
  }
  </script>
    
     
    

</div>
```

Comment: You guys are great! Thank you very much!